# Converting from one collection to another

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to iterate over one collection `moduleList` and adding to another collection `targetList`

Is this a good practice in Java 8? Do we have better way of doing this?

```
modulesList.forEach(
        m -> targetList.add(new ModuleType().withModuleNum(m.getLeft()).withModuleName(m.getRight())));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you gave more information on what `res` and `res.getModules()` are.

But even without having more information, this can be refactored to be more readable.  You are bunching together the logic of building `ModuleType` with mutating a collection of results.  While mutable collections aren't always avoidable, it's best to keep mutation separate from computation.  So let's start by separating the making of `ModuleType` from storing it:

```
bitDao.getResearchModules().stream()
    .map(m -> new ModuleType().withModuleNum(m.getLeft()).withModuleName(m.getRight()))
    .forEachOrdered(res.getModules()::add);
```

Is this the only place in your code where you need to obtain `ModuleType` from a `Module`?  If not, consider making this operation a method on `Module`class  (`m.type()`)  or a static method on `ModuleType` (`ModuleType.fromModule(m)`).  Now your bit of code becomes clearer:

```
bitDao.getResearchModules().stream()
    .map(ModuleType::fromModule)  // or .map(Module::type)
    .forEachOrdered(res.getModules()::add);
```

As for the last part, it would require knowing more about `res.getModules()` to help with the refactoring.  Does `res.getModules()` return a pre-existing possibly non-empty collection that needs to be updated or does it start being empty?  Is it a `Set` or a `List` or something else?